# Web SQL game - passing extra arguments to an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I'm trying to make a javascript game and I'm using WebSQL to store game data. I have created my own database selection function that formats the query results and then returns them.

In this specific instance I pass the returned object to the outcomes function. I would like to also pass in two other variables but I keep getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: planetInfo is not defined". If anyone could help It'd be very appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

I have also tried using "selectRowPlanets('query',outcomes(shipInfo, arrivalNumber));", but still no luck.

```
/** db.js **/ 
function selectRowPlanets(query, callBack){ // <-- extra param
  var result = [];
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql(query, [], function(tx, rs){
      for(var i=0; i<rs.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rs.rows.item(i);
          result[i] = { id:          row['id'],
                        name:        row['name'],
                        owner:       row['owner'],
                        colum:       row['colum'],
                        row:         row['row'],
                        ships:       row['ships'],
                        production:  row['production'],
                        percent:     row['percent']
        }
      }
      callBack(result); // <-- new bit here
    }, errorHandler);
  });
}


/** function.js **/
function selectDestination(shipInfo, arrivalNumber) {
    selectRowPlanets('SELECT * FROM planets', outcomes(planetInfo, shipInfo, arrivalNumber));
}   

function outcomes(planetInfo, shipInfo, arrivalNumber){
        console.log(arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this code:

```
selectRowPlanets('query', outcomes(shipInfo, arrivalNumber));
```

The *output* of `outcomes(shipInfo, arrivalNumber)` is passed as the callback, not the actual function.

Make an anonymous function wrapper that calls your code:

```
selectRowPlanets('query', function() { outcomes(shipInfo, arrivalNumber) });
```